# How to chose the condition for expand in hash-table?

Tags: data-structures, arrays, hash-tables

How can I chose the condition for expanding of the array in chain-hashing if I want that given some cell (that contains elements) , the number of cells that I need to move about them is O(1) until the next cell that contains elements?

And in addition, I want that - the number of cells that I need to move about them between cell without elements to other cell with elements is O(1) too?

Comment: "the number of cells that I need to move about them" -- please rephrase, unclear what do you mean by this